# Pass output to new job in azure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, release

I am looking for some help passing the output from a powershell script into another task in a release pipeline.

The workflow is as follows:

[image]

I need to pass a variable that is created from the powershell script into the Manual intervention text message.

In a yaml pipeline, I would use

```
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar;isOutput=true]foo"
```

however in order to access this it only works if the previous task was a dependant, which I do not believe you can do in a release pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's true. In YAML pipelines, you can set variables at the root, stage, and job level. You can also use a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops) to make variables available across multiple pipelines. Some tasks define output variables, which you can consume in **downstream steps, jobs, and stages**.

Coming to YAML, you can access variables across jobs and stages by using [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies). By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. If you need to refer to a stage that isn't immediately prior to the current one, you can override this automatic default by adding a `dependsOn` section to the stage.

For example, let's assume we have a task called `MyTask`, which sets an output variable called `MyVar`. To use outputs in a different job:

```
jobs:
 - job: A
  steps:
  # assume that MyTask generates an output variable called "MyVar"
  # (you would learn that from the task's documentation)
 - task: MyTask@1
    name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step
 - job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    # map the output variable from A into this job
    varFromA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
  steps:
 - script: echo $(varFromA) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

For more details on the syntax and examples, check the following articles:

- [Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)
- [Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies)